# Executing sh file with sudo in OS X gives an error

Tags: objective-c, macos, bash, sudo, nstask

I've developed an application where I need to run some script under root. Also sh script contains "sudo" commands. For running sh script under root I use STPrivilegedTask class from github:
https://github.com/sveinbjornt/STPrivilegedTask

Here how I run a script:

```
NSString *scriptPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_script" ofType:@"sh"];
STPrivilegedTask *task = [[STPrivilegedTask alloc] initWithLaunchPath:scriptPath];
int result = [task launch]; // return error 60031 which means:
//errAuthorizationToolExecuteFailure      = -60031, /* The specified program could not be executed. */
```

And here is a script I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/myfolder
sudo su - root -c "launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mydaemon.daemon.plist"
```

I use OS X Mavericks 10.9.4

EDIT:
After I set "chmod +x my_script.sh" for script it runs script. But now I receive next errors in console:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Seems that my admin credentials I put didn't applied with script I run. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Have you set the script's permissions to executable? try `chmod +x script.sh` in the folder you saved the script in.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I solved the problem. It runs script. But now I receive an error in console:
"sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Comment: thats because `sudo` has to ask you for your password to switch to the root account, and it needs an interactive prompt (`tty`) or a program to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two solutions taken in part from [this stackexchange thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23494/what-option-should-i-give-the-sudo-command-to-have-the-password-asked-through-a), which I can't test because I do not currently own a mac.

### Solution 1: Use OSAScript to run the command in the first place

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/myfolder
osascript -e "do shell script \"mkdir -p /usr/local/myfolder\" with administrator privileges"
osascript -e "do shell script \"launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mydaemon.daemon.plist\" with administrator privileges"
```

### Solution 2: Use OSAScript to prompt for a password and use that with sudo

```
#!/bin/bash
pw = "$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Password:" default answer "" with hidden answer' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)"

echo $pw | sudo -S mkdir -p /usr/local/myfolder
echo $pw | sudo -S su - root -c "launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mydaemon.daemon.plist"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `STPrivilegedTask` properly, then the script should already be running with root privileges so the `sudo` commands are actually not needed in that case.

You should use something akin to:

```
sudo=
[[ $(id -u) != 0 ]] && sudo=sudo
$sudo <command that would need sudo>
```

which should prevent the errors about not having a tty, which are related to invoking the `sudo` command in a GUI application.

Comment: I didn't know `STPrivilegedTask`, and this is probably the "more correct" answer, mine is more of a hack.